# Where should I store data extracted from a TXT file to retrieve it easily for later use?

Tags: c++

I am making a C++ application where I will get student information like name, exam score etc from a .txt file. I need to store this information in a table from where I could retrieve it easily. The operations I need to perform are:

1. Sorting based on name.
2. Sorting based on score of a particular subject.
3. Sorting based on overall score.
4. Search score by name.

I don't have to modify any of this data.

I don't have any experience in building real world project so I have no idea about doing this. The text file will be deleted after it has been read by the app. Each student is uniquely identified by string `studentcode`. Once a student has been added to this table, I also need support for adding some more exam scores for that student.

I am working on Windows and this is a personal project for learning purpose so I am free to choose any tools or libraries. Thanks for your help.

Comment: why is the file deleted? think about database?

Comment: @RCBrand I did not know about databases. Which one is the easiest to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using a structure.
For example:

```
struct students
{
     int name;
     int scoremath;
     int scoreenglish;
     int scoreoverall;
     int lettergrade;
}
```

Then you could use ifstream to read the data from the text file and fill out your structure. (Hint: Make a function that does this)

Comment: I want to store the data permanently and in a secure way (should not be modified by anyone) Sorry I should have added this in the question.

Comment: That's a good start.  Might want `studentcode` in there too, unless there's a `std::map<std::string, students>` where `studentcode` is the map key.  A simple alternative is a `std::vector<students>` with brute-force resorting / searching on demand.  Additional `map`s could be used to maintain simultaneous indices for each key field.  @reb94: security is best address by Operating System permissions on the "permanent" file you load from.  Write the in-memory content back to file to update it.

Comment: @TonyD Will a database like MongoDB or PostgreSql be appropriate in this situation? If not, then what are they used for. A brief explanation would suffice. Thanks.

Comment: @reb94: I don't think they're appropriate, as the administration / setup overheads will slow down your learning to program.  The libraries, tools and language (e.g. SQL) needed to use them are collectively much more complicated than reading/writing a few structs from/to file, so best left until you're more settled into the C++ language and day-to-day programming tasks.  There's a lot you can do without a database, but not much you can do until you understand structs, maps, vectors, strings, for-loops etc..

Comment: @TonyD I am comfortable working with STL containers and loops and have already coded something like that: http://ideone.com/oAQ2a7 The code is not complete but I can do it. So I was thinking about using a database to learn more.

Comment: @reb94: from a 30 second look that's promising, though you should search on S.O. for why `while (....eof())` loops don't work / why to use `while (getline(...))`, and try passing read-only function arguments by `const` reference to avoid unnecessary copying.  Learning to use e.g. `std::istringstream iss(line_from_file); if (iss >> first_word >> some_number >> another_word) ...` would simplify the kind of parsing you're doing in `getinfo`.  If you're comfortable with `map` too and curious about databases, go for it ;-).  Doing anything you're interested in is always good.